# Tutorial for browser-sync setup for Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail, gulp-browser-sync

I am new to python world and finished Codeforeveryone Wagtail videos.

I have wireframe website that I have added to Wagtail but could not figure out how to get browser-sync to work. Could anyone suggest what I need to do to get this browser-sync setup working so that html, css, scss update automatically after I hit the save button?